# Country border/boundary lat and long co-ordinates

Tags: android, google-maps, coordinates, polygon, latitude-longitude

I'm creating an Android application, which draws polygon shapes over a country.

I have a file which contains country lat and long coordiantes. For some of these countries I could draw a polygon on top of it, however for others it wasn't working. 
I then realised that the lat and long coordinates for those countries which weren't working didn't finish with the same coordinates as they had started with.

eg: 158.866,-54.75 .....(more lats and longs) 158.866,-54.75

I have tried simply adding those points to the end of the coordinates but that doesn't work.

So basically I was wondering if anyone knew where it would be possible to get lat and longs for the entire border for each country in the world - which could then be used to draw a polygon.

Any help would be appreciated - I have literally been looking for days! Thanks.

Comment: It would depend on who defines the borders. You will find that for example the shape of china is different depending on who you ask.

Comment: Yeah sure, but the shape doesn't particularly matter, it just needs to be generally accepted as the shape of China.

Answer (score 1):

If you're prepared to do some work extracting polygons from shapefiles, then boundaries of countries are widely available in this format:

http://gadm.org/country

http://wwwn.cdc.gov/epiinfo/html/shapefiles.htm

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors/

http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php

[QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/) is free GIS software that would help in this regard, but there's probably many other solutions out there for extracting data from shapefiles.